# minikube start error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" on win10

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, minikube

I want to build up the kubernetes environment on my local win10 system.

Installed virtualBox and minikube on my win10 laptop.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube version
minikube version: v0.28.2
```

Then try to start the cluster by follow command:

> minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox  --logtostderr

After "Starting cluster components...", 
it says error as below

**

> `I0817 15:12:23.987899   16328 kubernetes.go:119] error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" [Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=k8s-app%3Dkube-proxy: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.]`

**

```
c:\>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox  --logtostderr
I0817 15:09:34.548089   16328 notify.go:121] Checking for updates...
W0817 15:12:07.142500   16328 notify.go:55] Error getting json from minikube             version url: error with http GET for endpoint https://storage.googleapis.com  /minikube/releases.json: Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases.json: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
I0817 15:12:07.146468   16328 cluster.go:73] Skipping create...Using existing machine configuration
I0817 15:12:07.215164   16328 cluster.go:82] Machine state:  Running
I0817 15:12:08.078499   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/docker/ca.pem
I0817 15:12:08.086434   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker
I0817 15:12:08.100817   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/docker/server.pem
I0817 15:12:08.109746   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker
I0817 15:12:08.125123   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/docker/server-key.pem
I0817 15:12:08.133058   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
I0817 15:12:10.446177   16328 kubeadm.go:208] Container runtime flag provided with no value, using defaults.
I0817 15:12:10.447656   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /usr/bin/kubeadm
I0817 15:12:10.448151   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /usr/bin/kubelet
I0817 15:12:10.472953   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /usr/bin
I0817 15:12:10.473450   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /usr/bin
I0817 15:12:16.609853   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service
I0817 15:12:16.616802   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /lib/systemd/system
I0817 15:12:16.628703   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
I0817 15:12:16.637136   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
I0817 15:12:16.650031   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.657969   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib
I0817 15:12:16.672351   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/storage-provisioner.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.679309   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/addons
I0817 15:12:16.695662   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/dashboard-dp.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.704096   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/addons
I0817 15:12:16.716991   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/dashboard-svc.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.725918   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/addons
I0817 15:12:16.739808   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/kubernetes/manifests/addon-manager.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.754687   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
I0817 15:12:16.773038   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /etc/kubernetes/addons/storageclass.yaml
I0817 15:12:16.779982   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/addons
I0817 15:12:16.796847   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload &&
sudo systemctl enable kubelet &&
sudo systemctl start kubelet

Setting up certs...
I0817 15:12:16.946945   16328 certs.go:47] Setting up certificates for IP: 192.168.99.100
I0817 15:12:16.998033   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/ca.crt
I0817 15:12:17.006465   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.020353   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/ca.key
I0817 15:12:17.029282   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.045153   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/apiserver.crt
I0817 15:12:17.052099   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.065489   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/apiserver.key
I0817 15:12:17.072929   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.094753   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/proxy-client-ca.crt
I0817 15:12:17.104176   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.117075   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/proxy-client-ca.key
I0817 15:12:17.124513   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.138401   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/proxy-client.crt
I0817 15:12:17.145348   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.158737   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/certs/proxy-client.key
I0817 15:12:17.166177   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube/certs/
I0817 15:12:17.179570   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo rm -f /var/lib/localkube/kubeconfig
I0817 15:12:17.187505   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run: sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/localkube
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
I0817 15:12:17.370509   16328 config.go:101] Using kubeconfig:  C:\Users\DanDanWu/.kube/config
Starting cluster components...
I0817 15:12:17.382908   16328 ssh_runner.go:57] Run:
sudo kubeadm alpha phase certs all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase controlplane all --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml &&
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm alpha phase etcd local --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml

I0817 15:12:23.987899   16328 kubernetes.go:119] error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" [Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=k8s-app%3Dkube-proxy: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.]
I0817 15:12:25.493279   16328 kubernetes.go:119] error getting Pods with label selector "k8s-app=kube-proxy" [Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=k8s-app%3Dkube-proxy: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target   machine actively refused it.]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQJKE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbB4R.png

Comment: Could somebody help to have a look?Thanks very much!

Comment: Could you tell me where did you run the minikube? Looks like you tried to run it in Ubuntu for Windows and it does not work here. Did you try to run it in PowerShell or CMD?

Comment: Tried another way and fixed this issue by uninstall virtualBox and install dockerToolBox, then it works.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I run it in  CMD of Administrator.But I tried another way and bypass this issue.Thanks all the same!